# Looking for Specific PVC Trim Dimensions - Need Help!

Tags: walls, siding, materials

I'm currently working on a project and I'm in need of some specific PVC trim. I've been trying to locate the PVC trim board that the host is holding (see the image below). I know the hole at the center of the PVC trim board is 6 inches by 6 inches, so I think the board measures 10 inches by 10 inches by 1 inches or more, but I'm having some difficulty locating this size at my local home improvement stores.

Does anyone know where I could find a PVC trim board of these dimensions? Or, if you've purchased something similar before, could you suggest specific stores or online retailers that might carry this size?

Also, if there's a more technical term or specific keyword I should be using to search for this product, I'd really appreciate the advice. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

[image: Need to find the name of this PVC board]

Comment: I would think something like vent opening/cover than trim board.

Comment: Google ‘siding mounting block’. At a glance, I didn’t see the size you want, but it’s bound to be out there.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? https://dryerwallvent.com/mount/index.htm  Is your wall flat, or do you have siding?

Answer (score 0):

At these sizes, they aren't really "trim" boards anymore, although some manufacturers/sellers still refer to them as that.

You should look for "PVC 3/4" White PVC Sheet" and you can get that in a variety of sizes. You might have a hard time finding it stocked in a store, but it can be found online readily and you can always custom order it if need be.

Comment: I was able to order cellular pvc in (1/2", 3/4" ) 4'x8' sheets from a building supply center - not a big box.  You can then cut whatever pieces you need.  Some big box places have cellular 3/4" pvc fascia in 1x8 so if you only need a 7"x7" piece that can work as well.